# Google Analytics on multiple site clash and returned getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I try to use GA on multiple sites using the newer async code :

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-50706946-1', 'auto', {'name' : 'account1'});
  ga('account1.send', 'pageview');


</script>

<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-48177127-1', 'account2');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

One of them is working, I wonder why.. I use GA debugger and I see this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null em.js:1
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: No idea about the error, but shouldn't your second tag be set up the same way like the first (i.e. third parameter cookie domain, fourth parameter configuration object with the tracker name) ? And shouldn't the tracker name in the pageview call match the tracker name from the create call in the first snippet ?

Comment: @EikePierstorff don't get you, example?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is linked that you are duplicating the full tag for each object

Have a look at the section "Working with Multiple Tracking Objects" within the devguides https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced?#multipletrackers

that shows that you do can initiate multple tracking objects within 1 script.